# Add key value to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push a key-value pair in the 1st element

Like this

```
 updatedPlatingProcs = [{
    "data":{
     "AsfTime":1,
     "newKey":"newValue" -- // this is where I wanna add the new key-value pair
    },
    "data2":{
     "Asf":3
    }
}]
```

I tried something like this

```
       var platingTimeVal = {
           PlatingTime: processArea * time,
       };
       updatedPlatingProcs[0]["data"].push(platingTimeVal);
       updatedPlatingProcs.push(platingTimeVal); // also this
```

Got wrong results

Comment: `updatedPlatingProcs[0]["data"]` is an Object, not an Array. You can not use the `push` method on an Object. This `updatedPlatingProcs.push(platingTimeVal);` should actually work.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is that `data` in `updatedPlatingProcs[0]["data"]` is not an array, it is an object.

You can set a value of that object like so:

```
updatedPlatingProcs[0].data.PlatingTime = processArea * time;
```